# WP-ecommerce Custom fields

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, custom-fields

I have a wordpress e-commerce site with a plug-in installed Custom fields Version 1.4.5...

I added a new attribute called size and its a drop-down menu. it only shows up in the admin pages when I goto edit a product, but in wpsc-single_product.php it does not appear just one line of text. How do i get the drop-down to display on wpsc-single_product.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields manually to your theme by adding the following line:

```
<?php if( function_exists( 'wpsc_the_custom_fields' ) ) wpsc_the_custom_fields( 'slug=' ); ?>
```

Make sure to append your custom field slug to "slug="

e.g. 'slug=my-dropdown'